# Decorators for class-based views that use class variables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a class-based view that is inherited by other views:

```
class EditProfileAttribute(View):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    ThisModel = models.Model
    def get(request, model_id):
        instance = self.ThisModel.objects.get(id=model_id)
        if instance.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden.")
        # add form here
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'model_id':model_id})

    def post(request, model_id):
        instance = self.ThisModel.objects.get(id=model_id)
         if instance.user != request.user:
             return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden.")
         # do some editing here, save forms, etc.
         return HttpResponse("Edited")

class EditAddressView(EditProfileAttributeView):
        ThisModel = Address

class EditLinkView(EditProfileAttributeView):
        ThisModel = Link
```

Now in my models.py file:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=100)

class Link(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_link')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_link')
```

The class `EditAddressView` works because the User field is explicitly called `user`, but the class `EditLinkView` does not because it requires `instance.from_user` instead of `instance.user`. (Let's just say I can't rename `from_user`).

What I'd like to do is to transform the `instance.user != request.user` part into a decorator where the syntax `user` is not required, but I can't figure out how to reference `self.ThisModel`.

At the same time, this allows me not to repeat the same method for both `get` and `post`.

Is what I want even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another class attribute to store the name of the user field, and then use `get_attr` to fetch the value in the method.

If you want to avoid duplicating code in `get` and `post`, then factor the common code into a helper method, or override `dispatch` instead.

```
class EditProfileAttribute(View):
    ThisModel = models.Model
    user_field_name = 'user'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         self.instance = self.ThisModel.objects.get(id=kwargs['model_id'])
         if getattr(self.instance, self.user_field_name) != request.user:
             return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden.")
         # calling super() will call get() or post() as appropriate
         return super(EditProfileAttribute, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair! That solves my first problem -- but I have another one. What if I have a POST method that requires the same instance check? Is there really no way around having to copy the same line in both the get() and post() methods?

Comment: Also, what if I have a DeleteView that also requires a similar check? It would help much if I don't have to copy the same lines over and over again...

Comment: You can override the `dispatch` method to avoid duplicating code in `get()` and `post()`. The code above should work as a mixin, I can't see why your `DeleteView` can't inherit it.